# Laravel 5.2 - Paginator appending checkbox array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Is it possible to append a checkbox array to the paginator? for example I have the following form:

```
<form method="GET" action="/search" >

   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1" {{ in_array('bar1', $foo) ? 'checked': '';}}>
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2" {{ in_array('bar2', $foo) ? 'checked': '';}}>
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3" {{ in_array('bar3', $foo) ? 'checked': '';}}>

   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

 @foreach($users as $user)
    //list users
 @endforeach

{{ $users->appends(['foo' => $foo ])->links() }}
```

And a controller action as follows:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $foo = $request->input('foo');

    // Get all users where they have foo
    $users = $this->userRepository->getByFilters($foo)->paginate(10); 

    return view('search', compact('users', 'foo');
}
```

If bar1 and bar2 are selected the Paginator links should generate:

```
/search?foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2
```

Or should I be passing form array values in url for paginator links some other way i.e. exploding or imploding the foo array?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The method `appends` of the paginator might not work with arrays, you can try calling it for each item of your array.

Answer (score 0):

When you're appending data to the pagination links by doing `{{ $users->appends(['foo' => $foo ])->links() }}`, this sets the values when the php script executes. Therefore it won't be altered on changing the form element.

If you need to detected the checked items and append them to the links before the user clicks on them, you might have to go with the JavaScript approach.

From your code i can see that the form items get submitted and the respective pagination should contain the previously selected options. For this you can append the request query string in the backend when you paginate the result.

```
$users = $this->userRepository->getByFilters($foo)->paginate(10);
$users->appends(request()->query());
```

Comment: if you use `$users->appends(request()->query());` how can you exclude certain fields if need be?

Comment: @adam78 To only take the required fields `request()->only('foo', 'bar');`, to skip some fields `request()->except('foo', 'bar');`

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the code as follows so now the query string values for a checkbox array are generated as comma separated values. If anyone knows a more elegant soultion feel free to comment and improve.

Form

```
 <form method="GET" action="/search" >
   <?php $checkedFoo = explode(',', $foo); ?>

   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1" {{ in_array('bar1', $checkedFoo) ? 'checked': '';}}>
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2" {{ in_array('bar2', $checkedFoo) ? 'checked': '';}}>
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3" {{ in_array('bar3', $checkedFoo) ? 'checked': '';}}>

   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

 {{ $users->appends(['foo' => $foo ])->links() }}
```

Controller action

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $foo = is_array($request->input('foo')) ? implode(",",   $request->input('foo')) : $request->input('foo');

    $users = $this->userRepository->getByFilters($foo)->paginate(10); 

    return view('search', compact('users', 'foo');
}
```

If bar1 and bar2 are selected the Paginator links now generate:

```
?foo=bar1,bar2
```